# How to add a single line image list that is horizontal scrollable (in react js)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to get some suggestions/solutions and methods on how to add in a single line image list that is horizontally scrollable. Given that you have a html page, with multiple div elements and the page is vertically scrollable. And at the last row of the page, I want to display a list of images that can be horizontally scrollable. What can be done to achieve this effect? Please refer to the following image. The red line box is the component in react js that display the list of images.

[image]

Comment: so, are you using react? and if so, you can find some slick carousal packages of react which gives the same result you are trying to find.

Comment: Hi @Drystan, Yes i m using react and with MUI. Okay, thanks for the info, i will take a look at this packages then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in plain html and using css than you can try it out this and if you want to do this in react then [Check out this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick)

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu div:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <div class="#home">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615463738213-b9381d217b4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="#news"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578301978018-3005759f48f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1144&q=80"></div>
  <div class="#contact"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"></div>
  <div class="#about"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581337204873-ef36aa186caa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1156&q=80"></div>
  <div class="#about"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581337204873-ef36aa186caa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1156&q=80"></div>
  <div class="#about"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581337204873-ef36aa186caa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1156&q=80"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Drystan, thank you so much for the fast response! Appreciate! That's brilliant.

Comment: no worries it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code. This will help you to achieve your target.

```css
.singleLineImageContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #899;
  overflow: auto;
}
.image {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="singleLineImageContainer">
  <div class="image">Image1</div>
  <div class="image">Image2</div>
  <div class="image">Image3</div>
  <div class="image">Image4</div>
  <div class="image">Image5</div>
  <div class="image">Image6</div>
  <div class="image">Image4</div>
  <div class="image">Image5</div>
  <div class="image">Image6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mandeep Kaur, thanks for the solution! Appreciate!