# How to render singleline imagelist in rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a solution to build the following UI in the picture that I attached in the post in react. Plus, this post shares a linkage to another post that I have posted on the site as well: [How to add a single line image list that is horizontal scrollable (in react js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74023673/how-to-add-a-single-line-image-list-that-is-horizontal-scrollable-in-react-js).

The solution can be in the form of using MUI library or pure js and css. In the following image, the component SingleLineImageList contains a list of images.

I would like to render the image in the following sequence. The first two image will be in large and the next 4 images will each have 1/4 width and height of the larger size images and will be structured as the in the following (img 3 to 6). And, the cycle repeats. I have look for solution from MUI 4.0 imagelist library: https://v4.mui.com/components/image-list/#api and here is the sandbox code that I have created : [sandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-v4-imagelist-7ustjj?file=/src/App.js)
However, I do not have a solution on rendering the 4 images using loop iteration as per shown in the following image. Can anyone give some idea/ advice on this, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a solution using grid css and doing a brute force method

Here is the codesandbox link [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-list-in-vanilla-js-version-2-hh8k1v)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).